# How to redirect user after performing some java script in php

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I use php, html and sweetalert2 java script functions to show some notifications to the user. I need show an alert after redirecting the user to the same (targeted) page. This is the code I have

```
function delete_cat(){
        include("include/db.php");
        include("include/notification.php");

        $delete_cat_id = $_GET['delete_cat'];
        $delete_cat= $con->prepare("DELETE FROM main_cat WHERE cat_id='$delete_cat_id'");

        if($delete_cat->execute()){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                deleteMainCatSuccess();
                </script>';
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php?viewall_cat','_self')</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                deleteMainCatError();
                </script>';
        }
    }
```

And this is the notification java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function deleteMainCatSuccess(){
        swal({ 
              title: "Success",
              text: "Delete Main Category Success",
              type: "success", 
              timer: 3000
        },
             function(){
                //event to perform on click of ok button of sweetalert
        });
  }
</script>
```

This works, but the notification shows for less than 1 second, after redirect the page. I need stay some time to show notification and then redirect user to my target page. I have included `timer: 3000` in the options, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Move the `window.open` call to the `swal` callback function.

Comment: where i can learn it? can you give reference please :)

Comment: Your code is incredibly dangerous.  You're wide open to SQL injection attacks... use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this issue entirely.  You're also making changes on an HTTP GET request.  This violates various standards and makes you susceptible to cross-origin attacks as well.  There's a `DELETE` verb.  If you're deleting something, use it.  For data updates, use `POST` or `PUT` as appropriate.

Comment: Im using PDO i think i can reduce SQL injection attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Fixed it like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteMainCatSuccess(){
    swal({ 
          title: "Success",
          text: "Delete Main Category Success",
          type: "success", 
          timer: 3000
        }).then(function(){
            window.location.href='index.php?viewall_cat';
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
swal({ 
  title: "Success",
  text: "Delete Main Category Success",
  type: "success" 
},
function(){
  window.open('index.php?viewall_cat','_self');
});
```

Like this?